# System.ObjectDisposedException' with costum caret in WinForm C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, caret

In `C#` `WinForm` desktop application initialization I have custom  caret event handler:

```
 public Form1()
 {
      InitializeComponent();

      textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus); 
 }
```

then `textBox1_KeyDown` shows caret:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
        ShowCaret(textBox1.Handle); 
    }
```

And from `textBox1_TextChanged`:

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0) 
            {
                int x = 0;
                DrawCaret(textBox1, x);
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text.Length < 1)
            {
                int x = 1;
                DrawCaret(textBox1, x);
            }
       }
```

And:

```
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool CreateCaret(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hBitmap, int nWidth, int nHeight);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]

            static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

            void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int x = 1;
                DrawCaret(textBox1, x);
            }

            int size;
            public void DrawCaret(Control ctrl, int x)
            {      
                if (x == 0) { size = 2; }
                else { size = 15; }

                var nHeight = textBox1.Height;
                var nWidth = size;

                nHeight = Font.Height;

                CreateCaret(ctrl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, nWidth, nHeight); 
            }
```

I get:

> System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in ShowCaret(ctrl.Handle);

Which shows exception on code line:

```
CreateCaret(ctrl.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, nWidth, nHeight);
```

But attached to  `static extern bool ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);` above.

Can't figure out what causes this exception

Any guide, advice or example would be helpful

Comment: At what point in time is the exception thrown?

Comment: Also note from the Windows documentation that *CreateCaret automatically destroys the previous caret shape, if any, regardless of the window that owns the caret* - perhaps something else is not expecting its caret to be disposed behind its back...

Comment: @Matthew Watson Hello, I can't say for sure, different points in time, without direct connection with some process or action, except typing and entering text, which is processed without marks. Exception sometimes appears, sometimes not.

Comment: Why are you creating the caret over and over again? Also why don't you destroy the caret when textbox loses focus?

Comment: Why don't you search as i did for 10 seconds for `CreateCaret`? [CreateCaret function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createcaret) and [ShowCaret function](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcaret). In the end it has an example how to use one! Is this so difficult to do?

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε Hello, I'm trying to keep custom caret in textbox all the time as well as with `MouseHover` and `MouseMove` for `Form1` and `textBox1`

Comment: The articles and the example have all the info you need. Just read them.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε Yes, thank you